# SDL Web 8.5 - Linux CD Micro services - system start up to auto-start the start.sh

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, microservices, linux

Is there is any command or script there for auto-start the Linux SDL Micro services while restarting the machine rather than manually **start.sh**

Is that possible to automate to system start up a script on Linux?

Any help or comment would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting that you ask this question here, while it really isn't a Tridion related question (it would belong at https://superuser.com/, https://askubuntu.com, or equivalent), but I guess that is my opinion.

The answer is depending on your Linux distribution, but in general you can add the startup script to `/etc/rc.local`.

You can also create a full init script yourself and place that in `/etc/init.d/`, which is a lot more work.

And the dirtiest solution I can think of would be to set a crontab for this

```
#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/microservice/start.sh
```

after every startup it will run the start script.

Answer (score 4):

Linux systems come in more or less two main flavours: those whose startup is governed by [SystemV init.d scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), and those which use the more modern [SystemD](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd)

The details of getting your services to start on startup are not really a Tridion question, but a generic Unix/Linux one. So the answer is "Yes - it is possible to automate starting a script at system start up". For the details on how to do it, first check which kind of Linux system you have, and then check the relevant documentation for the type that you have.